# Callback from viewmodel to ui without data

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

How can I have my viewmodel call a function in my activity or fragment without using a callback and where no data is actually sent. LiveData is used to send data from the viewmodel to the view but I have no data. I just want to notify the ui about something. Should this be done using RxJava or is that overkill?

Comment: uhm, `LiveData<Unit>` ?

Comment: LiveData will only transmit updates if the value changes. Since no value is changing with Unit, then the observer will not get notified.

Comment: I didn't know that tbh. So you call twice post/setValue with the same value the `Observer` gets called only once?

Comment: Yes, LiveData is designed to only call the observer when the data changes, so if you  post the same value repeatedly, the observer will only get notified on the first post and only when it changes afterwards.

Comment: Actual `MutableLiveData` always notified when you call `setValue` method. just try.

Comment: I could be wrong, but the docs state the following: "Generally, LiveData delivers updates only when data changes, and only to active observers."

Comment: Yeah, i think the *data changes* means developer call the method,  for example. If data's type is `List`, and one item in the List has changed, the List has not actually changed. so, whether the change requires the developer to judge

Comment: yea but something will change before you trigger the LiveData, maybe a string or an int? Just pass that and the Value will always be different or use a Random() to have a changing value.

Comment: Might be an overkill for your case (and that's why this is a comment and not an answer), but you could implement an MVI-ish architecture where your state is represented by different state objects (or the same object with different parameters). This way, each state change is an object that gets emitted by your livedata.

Comment: What are you trying to actually do in the `Activity` that requires a `ViewModel` to signal to the `Activity` to invoke something? Surely you should just have 2 view model states (using view models in the generic sense, rather than platform specific implementation), one to cause the view to do what you want i.e show a `SnackBar`, the next to take it to the following state?

Answer (score 1):

LiveData is just fine, here is what I did recently (derived from https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)

first create a class

```
public class OneTimeEvent {

private Boolean received;

    public OneTimeEvent() {
        received = false;
    }

    public Boolean receive () {
        if (!received) {
            received = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

then in your ViewModel expose your event

```
 private MediatorLiveData<OneTimeEvent> eventListener = new MediatorLiveData<>();

public LiveData<OneTimeEvent> onEvent() {
    return eventListener;
}
```

now you have to trigger the event somewhere in your ViewModel (like something else is finished)

```
eventListener.setValue(new OneTimeEvent()); //if its a background thread or callback use postValue!
```

that's it, now you can observe onEvent() in any activity or fragment you like

```
ViewModel.onEvent().observe(this,  new Observer<OneTimeEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(OneTimeEvent oneTimeEvent) {
            if (oneTimeEvent.receive()){
                // do something on event
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps, it acts just like an EventListener, only that you can Listen from Multiple Locations simultaneously, and each event will only be fired once, eg if the observer is reattached somewhere else.

Comment: This is similar to the code under "Transform LiveData" at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata but this seems rather overkill. You are creating a new instance of OneTimeEvent every time you need get the observer triggered.

Comment: Yea, but why would that be a problem? It does work very well. You can always fall back to a regular Custom EventListener if that rather suits your needs, but this has some downsides like only being able to Listen from one location (activity/fragment). You could also just setValue("String") to trigger the observer, as you get notified at any the LiveData changes, this has the significant downside, that your observer will be triggered multiple times if reattached, this can be, depending on your design, quite damning.

Comment: Passing an EventListener from an activity/fragment to the view model means you are passing a reference of the view. That's bad, as the view model is not supposed to have any references to its view.

Comment: Not true, you don't have to pass a view you can just set a eventlistener to your viewmodel, in my case I had a timer run in the viewmodel or run a web query and need something to happen in the activity afterwards. It might by imported though to run on the mainLooper if views are affected and the viewmodel request is asynchronous.